# Why doesn't psycopg2 allow us to open multiple server-side cursors in the same connection?

Tags: psycopg2, amazon-redshift

I am curious that why psycopg2 doesn't allow opening multiple server-side cursors (http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors) in the same connection. I got this problem recently and I have to solve it by replacing the second cursor by a client-side cursor. But I still want to know if there is any way to do that.

For example, I have these 2 tables on Amazon Redshift:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl_account (
acctid varchar(100),
regist_day date
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_my_artist (
user_id varchar(100),
artist_id bigint
);

INSERT INTO tbl_account
(acctid, regist_day)
VALUES
('TEST0000000001', DATE '2014-11-23'),
('TEST0000000002', DATE '2014-11-23'),
('TEST0000000003', DATE '2014-11-23'),
('TEST0000000004', DATE '2014-11-23'),
('TEST0000000005', DATE '2014-11-25'),
('TEST0000000006', DATE '2014-11-25'),
('TEST0000000007', DATE '2014-11-25'),
('TEST0000000008', DATE '2014-11-25'),
('TEST0000000009', DATE '2014-11-26'),
('TEST0000000010', DATE '2014-11-26'),
('TEST0000000011', DATE '2014-11-24'),
('TEST0000000012', DATE '2014-11-24')
;

INSERT INTO tbl_my_artist
(user_id, artist_id)
VALUES
('TEST0000000001', 2000011247),
('TEST0000000001', 2000157208),
('TEST0000000001', 2000002648),
('TEST0000000002', 2000383724),
('TEST0000000003', 2000002546),
('TEST0000000003', 2000417262),
('TEST0000000004', 2000076873),
('TEST0000000004', 2000417266),
('TEST0000000005', 2000077991),
('TEST0000000005', 2000424268),
('TEST0000000005', 2000168784),
('TEST0000000006', 2000284581),
('TEST0000000007', 2000284581),
('TEST0000000007', 2000000642),
('TEST0000000008', 2000268783),
('TEST0000000008', 2000284581),
('TEST0000000009', 2000088635),
('TEST0000000009', 2000427808),
('TEST0000000010', 2000374095),
('TEST0000000010', 2000081797),
('TEST0000000011', 2000420006),
('TEST0000000012', 2000115887)
;
```

I want to select from those 2 tables, then do something with query result.
I use 2 server-side cursors because I need 2 nested loops in my query. I want to use server-side cursor because the result can be very huge.
I use fetchmany() instead of fetchall() because I'm running on a single-node cluster.

Here is my code:

```python
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import DictCursor

conn = psycopg2.connect('connection parameters')

cur1 = conn.cursor(name='cursor1', cursor_factory=DictCursor)
cur2 = conn.cursor(name='cursor2', cursor_factory=DictCursor)

cur1.execute("""SELECT acctid, regist_day FROM tbl_account
                WHERE regist_day <= '2014-11-25'
                ORDER BY 1""")
for record1 in cur1.fetchmany(50):
    cur2.execute("""SELECT user_id, artist_id FROM tbl_my_artist
                    WHERE user_id = '%s'
                    ORDER BY 1""" % (record1["acctid"]))
    for record2 in cur2.fetchmany(50):
        print '(acctid, artist_id, regist_day): (%s, %s, %s)' % (
            record1["acctid"], record2["artist_id"], record1["regist_day"])
        # do something with these values

conn.close()
```

When running, I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MLD1\Desktop\demo_cursor.py", line 20, in <module>
    for record2 in cur2.fetchmany(50):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\extras.py", line 72, in fetchmany
    res = super(DictCursorBase, self).fetchmany(size)
InternalError: opening multiple cursors from within the same client connection is not allowed.
```

That error occured at line 20, when I tried to fetch result from the second cursor.

Comment: Did you consider [opening an issue](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues) for this?

Comment: Oh, I didn't. Thank you for your kind suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

An answer four years later, but it is possible to have more than one cursor open from the same connection. (It may be that the library was updated to fix the problem above.)

The caveat is that you are only allowed to call `execute()` only once using a named cursor, so if you reuse one of the cursors in the `fetchmany` loop you'd need to either remove the name or create another "anonymous" cursor.